# is there a way to find someone on discord with only their username?

Tags: discord

I've searched for everything ie. videos and websites to find a way to add someone easily while only knowing their discord name. Every single one says the same thing  with no new information.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need username and tag to add someone. However, there's only 9999 tags, so you can add all 9999 tags, and if you know their avatar, you can see their profile picture when you send the friend request...

If you're talking about a discord bot, discord bots can't add people.